# Php reset for multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
$a=[
    [
        "a"=>1,
        "b"=>2,
    ],
    [
        "c"=>1,
        "d"=>2,
    ],
];
echo key(reset($a));
```

result

```
a
```

I need it to return the first index of the array which is 0, but it return 'a'.
Do i using it wrong way?

Comment: i also need to find the last key, i'm using end, but it return c not 1

Comment: Are you use it is a PHP Array? Coz we declare them like this: `array( );`

Comment: For the last, it's equal to size of your array -1

Comment: do you wan to reset?? or first and last key only?

Comment: If this is the actual code, whay do you need `reset()`?

Comment: @SuryaWono, check my answer and let me know is it okey or not? [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999418/php-reset-for-multidimension-array/36999590#36999590)

Comment: i got the answer, i should not put reset($a) inside key, must be reset($a) then key($a), @PraveenKumar you should update your php version

Comment: @SuryaWono Okay. Yes. I know. I am using PHP 5.4... `;)`

Answer (score 0):

> Reset — Sets the internal pointer of an array to its first element
>
> Key — Fetch a key from an array

so when you use `key` with `reset` it will return the key `a`.

with reset the `index` will always 0, the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$keys = array_keys($a);
$length = count($keys);

echo "First: ".$keys[0]; // 0
echo "Last: ".$keys[$length-1]; // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code you will get the first element and last key element.

```
echo key($a); // return 0
$lastkey = array_keys($a);
echo $lastvalue = end($lastkey); // return 1
```

Answer (score -1):

once you `reset`, your array will be:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
)
```

So `key` of the resultant is naturally `a`.

Now if you want `0`, then `key($a)` will just do!